# Congratulations to ProfRob on reaching 100k!

Tags: discussion, reputation

Recently, [ProfRob](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/43351/profrob) surpassed the 100k reputation threshold on Physics Stack Exchange, and as we've done for other users, I'd like to congratulate him on his efforts and his many contributions to the site. Only six other folks have reached 100k here, and ProfRob's accomplishment is doubly impressive because today he also passed 100k [on Astronomy Stack Exchange](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/2531/profrob), becoming the first person there to do so (as well as the first person to reach 75k, 50k, etc. - he's set more records than I can list). Congratulations to him on a pair of remarkable achievements!

Comment: Yeah, but look at that Biology score. :-)  Congrats.

Comment: Congratulations. Maybe some "laser" tag to celebrate.

Comment: Congratulations Professor Rob.

Comment: Congrats ProfRob, after so many excellent posts, well deserved!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thanks. I aimed for simultaneity, but missed by a week.

It's probably time to get on with some proper work now.

Comment: as if being a faculty member was actual proper work (or even *work*)...  Don't you have grad students to do proper work?

Comment: Should have posted on meta earlier, we would have upvoted you ferociously to get that double 100k :-)